# Can I use the cloudsql-proxy to connect to a custom VM running postgres?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I have a custom Postgres instance running on a GCE VM. I am *not* using CloudSQL. I'd like to use the functionality provided by the cloudsql-proxy, but when I specify my custom instance the proxy fails.

```
googleapi: Error 404: The Cloud SQL instance does not exist., instanceDoesNotExist
```

It appears that only CloudSQL instances work and I don't understand the limitation. It seems like the proxy should work on any VM with port 5432 open.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud SQL Proxy can only be used with Cloud SQL instances. 
In the documentation [About the Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) there is no mention about using it for custom databases inside GCE.
As it is stated in the documentation:

> The Cloud SQL Proxy provides secure access to your Cloud SQL Second
>   Generation instances without having to whitelist IP addresses or
>   configure SSL.

However, I found some documentation about [Access control overview](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/) where you can find an alternative to it.